# Read Stata with missing codes

Tags: r, stata, missing-data

I received a .dta file and they have funny missing codes such as: .mm and .x
If I read .dta file in R then all of these funny missing codes go to 'NA' and

I am wondering how do I keep them as .mm and .x for example?

Comment: Some R packages such as `foreign` and `readstata13` have an argument `missing.type = TRUE`. I have not used it myself though. If I want different missing values to be informative, I add some special values representing them before importing to R.

Comment: There is no missing code `.mm` in Stata. `.m` is allowed. The reason for them is easy to explain. Some researchers want to distinguish reasons for missing, such as not applicable, did not reply, unintelligible answer, and many more. In a well-documented project there will be a codebook or metadata explaining the codes used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stata allows you to code missing values from ".a" to ".z". It could be useful if the values are missing for different reasons etc. But they are missing nonetheless.

A quick work-around is to import the data as strings, and create a missing_flag variable to preserve the missing code information.

Comment: Just to add that `.a` to `.z` are kinds of missing numeric values in addition to the generic or system numeric missing `.`. String missing is just an empty string.