# Importing Stata data to R while maintaining missing values (.d, .r)

Tags: r, import, stata, missing-data

I am trying to import a dataset from Stata to R where I want to be able to identify the difference between missing (NA) and refuse to answer (.r) and don't know (.d). In Stata, these show up as extended missing values. But when I import the data into R they are all collapsed under NA.

https://www.stata.com/manuals/dmissingvalues.pdf

Ideally, I want them to all remain as missing but be able to distinguish between what type of missing (not answered, vs DK vs Refuse to answer).

Comment: Related, possible duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63403853/680068

Comment: What packages are you using for import, share you code, please.

Comment: Search for tags `stata`, `r`, `missing-data`.

Comment: The code that I use to import my dataset is the following. I use this approach because i am using Stata 16 so it allows me to import data from Stata with that version 
 my_attributes <- read_dta('file_path/dataset.dta')

Answer (score 1):

Evidently there isn't a one-to-one mapping meaning that R recognises different kinds of missing values in the way that Stata can.

As a frequent and long-term Stata user. but only a very occasional R user, my advice is to recode `.r .d` in Stata to distinct values that don't occur otherwise before you export. As R users may not know, Stata variables with these missing values must be numeric, so you need some choice of say integers 999 or -999 that can't be mistaken for other non-missing values. Such arbitrary codes should be in practice either smaller than, or larger than, other values, so that they appear as you wish in graphs and tables.

It would be good to hear of a better work-around.

Comment: I will do as you suggested. I saw that you gave a similar suggestion to another post and am not seeing other ideas. Thank you!